# Tracks in the snow

Tags: visual, word-search

Eleven fantastic creatures left their tracks in the snow. Can you identify all of them and the twelfth  creature that left no tracks?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [image: Solution]

Text solution:

> Each answer is in the grid in "reading order", starting with the cells I've specified. Cells are (row, column) starting in the top left.
> FAUN (3,6) / LAMIA (1,4) 
>  GRIFFIN (5,2) / OUROBOROS (3.2) 
> HARPY (7,6) / ROC (4,1) / WYRM (1,8) 
> HELLHOUND (7,1) / WYVERN (1,3) 
> HIPPOGRIFF (3,4) / YETI (1,1)

And the trackless creature is

> a WILL-O-WISP, found in the unused cells.